# Does variadic template function call lambda parameter in reverse order?

Tags: c++, lambda, language-lawyer, variadic-functions

The below [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/921bf635cc2df4f9) prints `21` instead of `12`.  Why?

```
#include <iostream>
template<class... F> void callMany(F... fib){
    [&](...){}(
        (fib(),123)... 
    );
}
int main()
{
    auto f1=[&](){std::cout<<"1";};
    auto f2=[&](){std::cout<<"2";};
    callMany(f1,f2);
}
```

I tested it with both vc++ and g++. Both result are the same.

Is it a standard behavior?   If so, which rules, and why?
Does it depend on compiler?

There is [a way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15904288/how-to-reverse-the-order-of-arguments-of-a-variadic-template-function) to reverse it, but I think it is a bit unrelated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an expression that contains a pack expansion is evaluated, the pack is expanded first---which simply instantiates the code, so to speak, without performing any evaluation---then the resulting expression is evaluated according to the usual rules. Your expression

```
[&](...){}(
    (fib(),123)... 
);
```

is expanded into

```
[&](...){}(
    (f1(),123), (f2(),123)
);
```

and since function arguments are evaluated in an unspecified order, you cannot rely on `f2` being called before `f1` or *vice versa.*

Comment: @cppBeginner Yes, there is, but I can't explain it in a comment. You should post a new question.