# Reversing the order of template (integer) parameters

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, c++17, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to reverse the order of a template-variadic `std::size_t` parameter sequence, based on an answer found in [a previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15908420/5778994). But for some reason it doesn't work.

Here's a regular variadic print function:

```cpp
template<typename = void>
void print(void)
{
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

template<typename... T>
void print(std::size_t index, T... indexes)
{
    std::cout << index << ' ';
    print(indexes...);
}
```

And here's the template class chain:

```cpp
template<std::size_t... Indexes>
class NonRecursiveClass
{
    public:

        void show(void)
        {
            print(Indexes...);
        }
};

template<std::size_t Count, std::size_t Index, std::size_t... Indexes>
class RecursiveClass;

template<std::size_t Count, std::size_t Index, std::size_t... Indexes>
class RecursiveClass : public RecursiveClass<Count - 1u, Indexes..., Index>
{
};

template<std::size_t Index, std::size_t... Indexes>
class RecursiveClass<0u, Index, Indexes...> : public NonRecursiveClass<Index, Indexes...>
{
};
```

Basically, the idea is that if you create, for instance, a `RecursiveClass<5u, 10u, 1u, 6u, 478u, 23u>` object, it will inherit from a `NonRecursiveClass<23u, 478u, 6u, 1u, 10u>` object and you have your `std::size_t` parameter sequence backward at compile time.

Unfortunately when I try it out, I still get the original order. Here's my main function:

```cpp
int main(void)
{
    RecursiveClass<5u, 10u, 1u, 6u, 478u, 23u> foo;
    foo.show();
    return 0;
}
```

And here's the output:

```
10 1 6 478 23
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

> What did I do wrong?

Think about what you're doing here:

```
template<std::size_t Count, std::size_t Index, std::size_t... Indexes>
class RecursiveClass : public RecursiveClass<Count - 1u, Indexes..., Index>
```

If you're not done yet (that is, if `Count != 0`), then what you do is you take the first one and move it to the back. Let's just follow through that algorithm:

```
RecursiveClass<5, 10, 1, 6, 478, 23>
└─ RecursiveClass<4, 1, 6, 478, 23, 10> // 10 to the back
   └─ RecursiveClass<3, 6, 478, 23, 10, 1> // 1 to the back
      └─ RecursiveClass<2, 478, 23, 10, 1, 6> // 6 to the back
         ...
```

We're not *reversing* the sequence. We're just rotating it one full rotation. That's why we end up printing the same thing.

What you need to do is *pre*-pend each element to a *different* sequence:

```
template <std::size_t...> struct sequence;

template <typename T, typename U>
class RecursiveClassImpl;

template <std::size_t I, std::size_t... Is, std::size_t... Js>
class RecursiveClassImpl<sequence<I, Is...>, sequence<Js...>>
    : public RecursiveClassImpl<sequence<Is...>, sequence<I, Js...>>
//                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                                               NB: prepend
{ };

template <std::size_t... Js>
class RecursiveClassImpl<sequence<>, sequence<Js...>>
    : public NonRecursiveClass<Js...>
{ };

template<std::size_t... Indexes>
class RecursiveClass : public RecursiveClassImpl<sequence<Indexes...>, sequence<>>
{ };
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir. I don't know what I was thinking, really. May I ask why you chose to make `sequence` a `struct` rather than a `class`? Most examples I saw seem to prefer `struct` and I was wondering why that might be :)

Comment: @Pippin Doesnt matter, it's not even a complete type. Metaprogramming tends to prefer `struct` because there isn't anything to encapsulate and it saves you having to type `public` everywhere.