# Can anyone explain how this produces a pack of ones and zeroes?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I'm asked to produce a template that can handle the digits... pack of binary and return the corresponding integer. However, I'm curious as to how the following code produces a binary pack. The only input I see is a 6. I can figure that 2^6 being 64 is related to the pack being 64 bits but how is it actually produced?

The following may also be relevant

[image]

The input may look something like this

```
2
65 1
10 0
```

The code is as follows

```
template <int n, bool...digits>
struct CheckValues {
    static void check(int x, int y)
    {
        CheckValues<n-1, 0, digits...>::check(x, y);
        CheckValues<n-1, 1, digits...>::check(x, y);
    }
};

template <bool...digits>
struct CheckValues<0, digits...> {
    static void check(int x, int y)
    {
        int z = reversed_binary_value<digits...>();
        std::cout << (z+64*y==x);
    }
};

int main()
{
    int t; std::cin >> t;

    for (int i=0; i!=t; ++i) {
        int x, y;
        cin >> x >> y;
        CheckValues<6>::check(x, y);
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: There's quite a lot that could be explained here. Could you clarify what you're confused by exactly?

Comment: reversed_binary_value is where I'm asked to create a template

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15904288/how-to-reverse-the-order-of-arguments-of-a-variadic-template-function)?

Comment: No, unfortunately